# JPA User Registration

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, user-registration

I am facing problem with JPA. I have a problem where I need to insert new user and setup its relationship with user at the same time.

==> Database Design is as following:

- SystemUsers:

UserName(pk)
Password

- SystemClassifiedGroups:

SystemClassifiedGroupName
UserName

==> I have written following logic in EJB

```
@Override
public void addUser(SYSTEM_CLASSIFIED_USER_GROUPS systemClassifiedUserGroup,
        String userName,
        String password,
        String emailID,
        String secretQuestion,
        String secretAnswer,
        String firstName,
        String lastName,
        String profilePictureURL,
        Date birthDate,
        String address1,
        String address2,
        String cityName,
        String zipCode,
        short stateID,
        short countryID,
        String officePhoneNumber) {

    FeedBack objFeedBack = null;
    String methodName = CLASS_NAME + ".addUser";

    try {

        SystemUsers objSystemUser=new SystemUsers(userName, password, emailID, firstName, lastName, address1, cityName);
        SystemClassifiedUserGroups tempGrp=new SystemClassifiedUserGroups(systemClassifiedUserGroup.name());

        States objState = new States(stateID);
        Countries objCountry = new Countries(countryID);
        objSystemUser.setSecretQuestion(secretQuestion);
        objSystemUser.setSecretAnswer(secretAnswer);
        objSystemUser.setProfilePictureURL(profilePictureURL);
        objSystemUser.setBirthDate(birthDate);
        objSystemUser.setAddress2(address2);
        objSystemUser.setStateID(objState);
        objSystemUser.setCountryID(objCountry);
        objSystemUser.setOfficePhoneNumber(officePhoneNumber);
        objSystemUser.setZipCode(zipCode);

        ArrayList<SystemUsers> lstUser = new ArrayList<SystemUsers>();
        lstUser.add(objSystemUser);
        tempGrp.setUserName(objSystemUser);
        tempGrp.setSystemClassifiedGroupName(systemClassifiedUserGroup.name());

        em.persist(tempGrp);

        em.persist(objSystemUser);

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

==> And call the method by following :

asr.addUser(SYSTEM_CLASSIFIED_USER_GROUPS.ADMIN, 
                    "raj", 
                    "pass", 
                    "abc@yahoo.com",
                    "Color",
                    "purple",
                    "Raj", 
                    "Champaneriya", 
                    "abj.jpg", 
                    new Date(),
                    "jolly1", 
                    "jolly2",
                    "surat",
                    "395007", 
                    (short) 1,
                    (short) 1,
                    "3201708");

==> But I got following Exception in glassfish console

```
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: BusinessFacade.Entities.SystemUsers[ userName=raj ] is not a known entity type.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4158)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:440)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:269)
at BusinessFacade.User.UserServices.addUser(UserServices.java:95)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at $Proxy273.addUser(Unknown Source)
at BusinessFacade.AdminServices.addUser(AdminServices.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor119.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:206)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)
at $Proxy271.addUser(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:241)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:152)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:227)
at BusinessFacade.__AdminServicesRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.addUser(BusinessFacade/__AdminServicesRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
at BusinessFacade._AdminServicesRemote_Wrapper.addUser(BusinessFacade/_AdminServicesRemote_Wrapper.java)
at Admin.TestServlet.processRequest(TestServlet.java:35)
at Admin.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:74)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your `SystemUsers` entity. You must put the `@Entity` annotation on every entity you use. Otherwise it won't be recognized by JPA.

Answer (score 1):

Show me the exact line in the code where the error occurs. I assume it is at the point you call em.persist(tmpGrp). You must save the user first, otherwise the EntityManager will not be able to find any instance of the user, or you need to specify the way the user is managed in the group by adding the following in the group class:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
SystemUsers userName;
```